# Calculate integral involving product of curls

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

I want to show that

$ \frac{1}{k^2} \int \,  (\nabla \times \vec M)\cdot (\nabla \times \vec M)^* d^3 r= \int  \vec M \cdot \vec M^*d^3 r$.

$\vec M$ is defined as

$\vec M_{jm} = i\frac{m}{\sin \theta} e^{i m\phi} P_j^m (\cos \theta) z_j(k r) \hat e_{\theta} - \,e^{i m \phi} \frac{d P_j^m (\cos \theta)}{d \theta} z_j (k r) \hat e_{\phi} $,

where j is an integer number $>0$, $m$ is between $-j$ and $j$, $P_j^m$ are the Legendre Polynomials, $z_j (kr)$ is the spherical Bessel function and the unit vectors $\hat e_i$ are those of spherical coordinates. The divergence of $\vec M$ is equal to zero.

Has anyone an idea how to show this? I couldn't find a formula like this in Bronstein or other formula tables and I couldn't figure it out by myself.

Comment: What does the superscript asterisk mean?

Comment: It means complex conjugation. $\vec M$ is in general a complex function.

Comment: Can you describe the context in which you're working? It might help us recognize what the proper approach is. (Particularly if $\vec{M}$ itself has some properties, such as being composed of special functions etc.)

Comment: I added the definition of $\vec M$, so now it should be clear what it is composed of.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathbf M$ is a constant vector field then $\nabla \times {\bf M} = {\mathbf 0}$, in which case the left integral is $0$. If $\mathbf M$ is nonzero, the right integral is positive (assuming the domain of integration has positive measure anyway), and so the equation cannot hold for general $\mathbf M$.

Comment: Ok, you are right. I corrected the assumptions.

Comment: The same basic argument works because there are nonconstant vector fields whose curl is zero; this is the case for the gradients of most functions.

Comment: Ok, then let's just assume that the curl is not zero (in the relevant case that I need this is the case). If more details regarding $\vec M$ are needed, I will provide it, but let's keep it a very general function as long as possible. The details, how $\vec M$ looks exactly would be very lengthy.

Comment: I don't think that anything like this is possible without more information about $\mathbf{M}$. One could always add $\nabla f$ to any $\mathbf{M}$ for any function $f$, and this would leave the left-hand integral alone but in general change the right-hand side.

Comment: Ok, I added the full definition of $\vec M$. The context is spherical expansion of a vector field (e. g. the current density).

Comment: If the identity is supposed to hold over a general solid region, then the integrands themselves must be equal (including the $k^{-2}$ on the LHS. Have you computed an expression for $\nabla \times \mathbf M$?